# Change my customize theme into transparent theme for my activity

Tags: android, android-styles

I have this customized theme which I want to convert into Transparent theme

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base"></style>
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base"
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
     <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
     <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
     <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
     <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: please select the answer that solved your problem/question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
      <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
      <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
      <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

The value `@color/transparent` is the color value `#00000000` which I put in `res/values/color.xml` file. You can also use `@android:color/transparent` in later Android versions.

Then apply the style to your `Activity`, for example:

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
...
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting these items

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style in your `values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And the following in `values/styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
</style>
```